# Deploying asp.net website under existing web site on FTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I have a web site underneath I want deploy another web application. So I created a folder in the ftp site and dumped all my file in it.

Example:

[image]

Now I am getting below error when trying to access my application default.aspx file

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 33:       </assemblies>
Line 34:     </compilation>
Line 35:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 36:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
Line 37:     </authentication>
```

I don't know root site asp.net version, but I developed on asp.net 3.5

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are the two sites related? Did you set the subfolder up as an application in IIS? The second certainly does not seem to be true - you have to configure the subfolder in IIS to be an Application.

Comment: @dash: I don't have access to IIS. I just have access to FTP access. Can I do something with FTP?

Comment: no, unfortunately you *need* to have access to IIS - perhaps you could get the site admin to help you?

Comment: How can I make this as a web site and deploy on the folder? I need app_data folder to access the some access database files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the subfolder as an IIS Application

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would need to go into IIS and ensure that the "OnlineReport" folder is configured as an application

Comment: I don't have access to IIS. I just have access to FTP access. Can I do something with FTP?

Comment: Is this website hosted by a hosting provider, if so you may need to contact them or they may have an administration function that allows you to do this yourself.